# How To Display Form Data Entry Errors in Wordpress Pods

Tags: wordpress, podscms

I want to display form entry errors, such as uniqueness error, to the user. I want the error to be displayed inside a notification box above the form.

Currently, pods gives data entry errors as javascript message boxes such as the following:

[image]

I want to display these error messages similar to success messages:

[image]

```
<div id="message" class="pods-form-front-success">Form submitted successfully</div>
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pods uses AJAX to submit the form, we do not yet have custom HTML-based errors available on the form fields themselves. For a more robust form solution, try Gravity Forms (http://gravityforms.com/) which you can map your form submissions over into a Pod using our API http://pods.io/docs/add/